# how to remove app that has been install from terminal

Tags: command-line, telegram

I have installed an app called telegram using terminal but right now i cant Remove it i tried every thing but nothing worked please help me here is how I did [install it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Pu-miD1f-s) please tell me how to remove this app and thank you For help.

Answer (score 4):

The package and repositories should be removed if you type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge telegram-desktop
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:noobslab/apps
```

The first command removes the program and the configuration files, the second removes the repository.

If you just want to remove the program, but not the configuration files, use remove instead of purge:

```
sudo apt-get remove telegram-desktop
```

Comment: If this works for you, please click on the check-mark icon right next to the content to accept this answer.